# Creating a connection with Java ODBC results in a java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Cursor Type exception

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, odbc

I am trying to create a Java program that accesses a ODBC datasource. Using the following code...

```
Connection conn;

try {
    Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
    DriverManager.registerDriver(d);
    String URL = "jdbc:odbc:AR System ODBC Data Source";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
} catch (SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Logger.error(this, e);
} 

Statement s = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    s = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    rs = s.executeQuery("select count(*) as rows from table");

    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.print("Count of all rows is " + rs.getInt("rows"));
    }
} catch (SQLException e) { 
     e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    DBUtils.safelyClose(s, rs);
}
```

...I get the following Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The result set type is not supported.
   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.initialize(Unknown Source)
   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.createStatement(Unknown Source)
   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.createStatement(Unknown Source)
   at com.csc.remedyarchiver.data.input.ODBCConnection.main(ODBCConnection.java:38)
```

Originally, when I was attempting to resolve this on my own, I was using the empty argument createStatement() call but this lead to the above exception (hence is why I used the TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY result set type but still the same result):

Is there anything else I can try with this or does this need a different approach?

Comment: check changing if to while.just telling 
while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.print("Count of all rows is " + rs.getInt("rows"));
}

Comment: @PiumiWandana - That didn't work with the Invalid Cursor Type exception.

Comment: Try adding `ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT` parameter in `createStatement()` to see if it helps

Comment: Try s = odbc.getConn().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

Comment: @DarshanLila - Adding that threw a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException exception.

Comment: @Sunny - That threw the unsupported result set type exception.

Comment: can you try this.call first();without if and tell me does it give a error too

rs = s.executeQuery("select count(*) as rows from table");
rs.first();
System.out.print("Count of all rows is " + rs.getInt("rows"));

Comment: @PiumiWandana - Yeah, that gave the same exception.

Comment: There is a Remedy AR JDBC driver mentioned [here](https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-22516) that might be of interest to you.

Comment: @GordThompson - It certainly is interesting but I cannot make it work from the client side without the rest of the jars that make up the server side of Remedy. Nevertheless, I'll keep looking at it. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

From the Oracle Documentation for retrieving data sets:

> Note: Not all databases and JDBC drivers support all ResultSet types.
>   The method DatabaseMetaData.supportsResultSetType returns true if the
>   specified ResultSet type is supported and false otherwise.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

So to start, you may want to check that your connection supports the result sets you are trying to use.

```
connection.getMetaData().supportsResultSetType(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY)
connection.getMetaData().supportsResultSetType(ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
```

The above methods both return true for my configuration. And for this reason the code you have posted works in my environment. I would bet that one of them (or both) will return false for you and my guess is that it is a problem with your database itself or the version of Oracle's JDBC driver you are using.  You may want to ensure you are using the latest OJDBC driver which you can get from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

If you have verified that you are using the latest driver, I would verify the version of the Database you are using, and the result sets supported by it.

Answer (score 0):

"select count(*) as rows from table" . Try first to replace the alias from "rows" to "Result" or something . Rows is one of the reserved keywords in Oracle . I don't think that select is returning any result besides an error ora 00923

Comment: The code doesn't reach that far as it doesn't initialise the statement object. Nevertheless, it is something to bear in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be worth trying the following, firstly to confirm that it's unsupported, then again with differing ResultSet types to find one that is?

```
System.out.println(conn.getMetaData().supportsResultSetType(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY));
```

Comment: For all three ResultSet types that Java 1.7 has, they all return false.

Comment: If they're returning false, it's never going to work for you. Perhaps an issue with the ODBC driver you're using? This guy seems to have the same problem and has worked around it using a different JDBC driver. http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/archive/index.php/t-3966.html